# android switch intent dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am trying to create a main menu activity in android which dynamically selects the activity destination from its position on the page.

MainMenu.java

```
package com.verscreative.BowlTrack;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainMenu extends SherlockActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        gridview.setAdapter(new HomeMenuAdapter());

        gridview.setPadding(50, 40, 50, 40);

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

                //Activities That are invoked by the click
                String[] mActivitiesIds = { 
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_0),
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_1),
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_2),
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_3),
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_4),
                        getString(R.string.menu_launch_5)
                        };

                String packageName = "com.verscreative.BowlTrack";
                String className = mActivitiesIds[position]+".class";
                //TODO: Switch Toast To Activity Intent
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setClassName(packageName, className);
                try{
                    startActivity(i);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Find Activity", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                activateSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }




    public void activateSettings(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }



    public class HomeMenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        public HomeMenuAdapter() {

        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView tv;
            if (convertView == null) {

                tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
                tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 10);

            } else {
                tv = (TextView) convertView;
            }

            tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, mThumbIds[position], 0, 0);
            tv.setText(mTextIds[position]);
            tv.setHeight(300);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            return tv;
        }

        // references to our images
        private Integer[] mThumbIds = { 
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_add,
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_view,
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_info_details,
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
                android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences
                };

        private String[] mTextIds = { 
                getString(R.string.menu_item_0),
                getString(R.string.menu_item_1),
                getString(R.string.menu_item_2),
                getString(R.string.menu_item_3),
                getString(R.string.menu_item_4),
                getString(R.string.menu_item_5)
                };

    }


}
```

However whatever I do it always says "Cannot Find Activity".

If I change:

```
String packageName = "com.verscreative.BowlTrack";
String className = mActivitiesIds[position]+".class";

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(packageName, className);
```

to for example:

```
Context packageName = MainMenu.this;
Class<ViewGamesActivity> className = ViewGamesActivity.class;

Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClass(packageName, className);
```

It works fine, but all options do the same thing!

---

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">BowlTrack</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="menu_item_0">Add New Game</string>
    <string name="menu_item_1">View Games</string>
    <string name="menu_item_2">Stats</string>
    <string name="menu_item_3">3-Not</string>
    <string name="menu_item_4">4-Not</string>
    <string name="menu_item_5">Settings</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_0">NewGameActivity</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_1">ViewGamesActivity</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_2">ViewOverallActivity</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_3">3-Not</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_4">4-Not</string>
    <string name="menu_launch_5">SettingsActivity</string>

    <color name="black">#000000</color>
    <color name="bwtk">#88078b</color>

    <string name="title_activity_view_games">View Games</string>

</resources>
```

ViewGamesActivity.java

```
package com.verscreative.BowlTrack;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;

public class ViewGamesActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    public class ViewGames extends ListActivity {

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

        // url to get all products list
        private static final String url_all_products = "http://api.androidhive.info/android_connect/get_all_products.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_games);

            // Hashmap for ListView
            productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            // Loading products in Background Thread
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            // Get listview
            ListView lv = getListView();

            // on seleting single product
            // launching Edit Product Screen
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String pid = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pid))
                            .getText().toString();

                    // TODO: Starting new intent
                    // Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    // EditProductActivity.class);
                    // sending pid to next activity
                    // in.putExtra(TAG_PID, pid);

                    // starting new activity and expecting some response
                    // back
                    // startActivityForResult(in, 100);
                }
            });

        }

        // Response from Edit Product Activity
        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            // if result code 100
            if (resultCode == 100) {
                // if result code 100 is received
                // means user edited/deleted product
                // reload this screen again
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
         * */
        class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewGamesActivity.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * getting All products from url
             * */
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products,
                        "GET", params);

                // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

                try {
                    // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                    int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    if (success == 1) {
                        // products found
                        // Getting Array of Products
                        products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                        // looping through All Products
                        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Storing each json item in variable
                            String id = c.getString(TAG_PID);
                            String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                            // creating new HashMap
                            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            // adding each child node to HashMap key =>
                            // value
                            map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                            // adding HashList to ArrayList
                            productsList.add(map);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // TODO: no products found
                        // Launch Add New product Activity
                        // Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        // NewProductActivity.class);
                        // Closing all previous activities
                        // i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        // startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                pDialog.dismiss();
                // updating UI from Background Thread
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        /**
                         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                         * */
                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                                ViewGamesActivity.this, productsList,
                                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_PID,
                                        TAG_NAME }, new int[] { R.id.pid,
                                        R.id.name });
                        // updating listview
                        setListAdapter(adapter);
                    }
                });

            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9923696/1616443

Comment: Remove the `+".class"` that you have. The fully qualified name of the class does not have a .class at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to jimpanzer and sherif-elkhatib, I have combined your comments to find the answer.

The Answer is Changing:

```
String className = mActivitiesIds[position]+".class";
```

to this:

```
String className = "com.verscreative.BowlTrack."+mActivitiesIds[position];
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to specify the *.class*

Try this
    String className = mActivitiesIds[position];

Otherwise, a more efficient solution would be to have a 2D array as such :

```
Object[][] mActivitiesIds = 
{ 
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_0), Activity1.class }
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_1), Activity1.class }
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_2), Activity1.class }
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_3), Activity1.class }
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_4), Activity1.class }
  { getString(R.string.menu_launch_5) Activity1.class }
};
```

Then simply use mActivitiesIds[n][1] to get the class...