# Android app auto boot fails - BroacastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, autostart

I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849868/startactivity-from-broadcastreceiver) how to make an application to start after Android OS boot is completed. I have done it good - I am catching the broadcast `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`, but unfortunately my app crashes and I cannot observe it with logcat because I have to reboot the device in order to see if my feature is working.

Does anybody know how can I catch an exception so I can see why my app is crashing OR does anybody know what could be the problem (if you have experienced the same problem)?

Comment: Wrap whatever you think might be crashing in a try catch; capture your own logs.

Comment: hey, I am relatively new with android, I have surrounded with try-catch... but don't know where to store the exception. Only what I know is to print it as Toast... can you explain me this a little bit please?

Comment: You can write to Logcat, check this link to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html)

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem... The initial intent was:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.example.app", "MainActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I made a toast with exception in it and made printscreen on emulator.

The exception said this:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

After checking, my activity was in the file. So I googled [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923602/cannot-start-new-intent-by-setclassname-with-different-package-in-android)
and made correction in my intent to:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName(context.getPackageName(), "com.example.app.sunshine.MainActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and `context.startActivity(i);` started the app after reboot.