# Unable to start activity by using the package name

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I am trying to use a library where I have to pass the action and the URI and to open the activity I have to use the package name but the thing is even I change the package name it is not working at all
this is the code that I am trying

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, Uri.parse(filename));
        intent.putExtra("was_get_content_intent", mWasGetContentIntent);
        intent.setClassName("neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid", "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_EDIT);
```

and this is my manifest code for setting the activity

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/edit_intent">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />

            <data android:mimeType="audio/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The package name is  `package="neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox"`
I know it is easy to open the activity by just calling the names of the activity but in this case i have to pass the action with a uri and this is the only possible way i can see and guide will be helpful .

Comment: Please explain, in detail, what "it is not working" means.

Comment: I mean I call this intent it just do nothing as there is no startActivity is called

Comment: Is the activity you want to start is in different application or same application?

Comment: Its in same application in ringdroid package

Comment: "there is no startActivity is called" -- you are calling `startActivityForResult()` in the fourth line of your first code snippet. When you make that call, you will either start the desired activity or crash with an `ActivityNotFoundException`. Since this appears to be an activity in your own app, a safer way to construct the `Intent` would be `new Intent(this, RingdroidEditActivity.class).setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT).setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filename), ...).putExtra("was_get_content_intent", mWasGetContentIntent);`, where `...` is replaced by the actual MIME type of this content.

Comment: @CommonsWare let me try it i will let you know

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried but it is still not able to open it ` Intent intent = new Intent(RingdroidSelectActivity.this, RingdroidEditActivity.class);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(filename),"media");
            intent.putExtra("was_get_content_intent", mWasGetContentIntent);
            startActivity(intent);`

Comment: `media` is not a valid MIME type, and it does not match the `<data>` element in your `<intent-filter>`. You should know what the actual MIME type is, since it is your file. If for some reason you do not, use `setData()` instead of `setDataAndType()`, and Android will try to guess based on things like the file extension. Also, my guess is that you have your code wrapped in a `try`/`catch` block, and you need to ensure that it logs errors to LogCat, so you can see these errors when you are debugging your app.

Comment: What is the value of `REQUEST_CODE_EDIT`?

Comment: @DavidWasser its is 1

Comment: Check this one:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923602/cannot-start-new-intent-by-setclassname-with-different-package-in-android

Comment: you should add full package name in manifest like : 
    neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidSelectActivity    | and also try to add flag for where you are trying to open this activity.. is it from background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your package name (in the manifest) is "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox". In that case you need to change this:

```
intent.setClassName("neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid", "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
```

to this:

```
intent.setClassName("neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox", "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
```

---

Since there are a number of ways to set the `Component`, you can also use any of the following methods:

```
intent.setClassName(this, "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
```

or like this:

```
intent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
```

or like this:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox", "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity"));
```

or like this:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity"));
```

or like this:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), "neelay.mediaplayer.beatbox.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity"));
```

Comment: yes @david wasser you are right this is what i was making mistake but can you add one more thing              intent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), "neelay.mediaplayer.tryal.ringdroid.RingdroidEditActivity");
this one also worked for me then it will be a complete ans

Comment: There are several ways to set the component, you can use any of them.